# Is there a ready utility for web sites to collect user information?

Tags: utility

The basic requirement is in look and feel.

It should look professional,have an good user interface.

I don't know if someone has already developed such a tool especially for doing this kind of job.

Comment: I think what you are looking for is an HTML form?

Comment: "this kind of job" being? Your question, I feel, is not quite as clear as you might want it to be.

Comment: Do you mean a create-your-own questionnaire site? Please rephrease the question.

Comment: What information?  When do you want to collect it?  Where do you want to store it?

Comment: @Dommy Zee,a form to collect user information,which has professional UI.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a form using [HTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/).  You can give it a professional-looking UI using [CSS](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/).  You will also need somewhere to store the data, e.g. a database, and some server-side code to query the database, e.g. PHP or ASP.NET.

This question is WAY to broad to be succintly answered.  Almost every question on StackOverflow is to do with "collecting information".

Answer (score 0):

Hm, I feel like you mean somthing like [google analytcs](http://www.google.com/analytics), but it's very unclear as others have stated before.

Answer (score 0):

Create a survey using [PollDaddy](http://polldaddy.com/) or [SurveyMonkey](http://www.surveymonkey.com/) to ask for this information and link to it.

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://wufoo.com/

Like the survey packages mentioned, this is a hosted service. But Wufoo prvoides generic HTML forms and other predefined web data collection templates. It lets you create your form or select one of their predesigned forms, it gives you javascript or HTML snippet to embed the form in your web page, and it gives you online tools to review and report on the submitted data.

On a programming site like this, most folks would just write their own web app to do this, but Wufoo and other sites offer comparable solutions for non-programmers.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, what data do you want to collect?

Let's take an easy one: Name...

- Christian Name, Surname
- Hang on, that's first name, surname because you don't want to offend non-christians
- Then family name and generational name
- And what about, say, Korean names so you don't upset Mr Kim, given name Jong-Il?
- Patronymics, nicknames, known as names
- Someone where the family tradition is to use middle name (like me)

Others:

- Insist on SSN? I'm British, don't have one
- Why must I trawl past 50 states in a dropdown in county/state?
- I live in Switzerland, we don't have counties
- UK? Britain? Great Britain?

The question can't be answered.